# Custom BlendState to avoid AlphaBlending artifacts

Tags: c#, colors, xna, draw, alphablending

I am essentially drawing a texture onto itself every frame, each time i draw it i want to decrement the alpha so that it eventually hits 0 so no artifacts are left.

The basic equation is:

```
result = (source * sourceBlendFactor) blendFunction (destination * destinationBlendFactor)
```

And since my destination is Color.Transparent I figure i need:

```
result = 0 = (source * sourceBlendFactor);
```

Im racking my brain going over the different BlendState components but I cant seem to acheive this...

Is there any way to have the alpha decrement linearly?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with 'C# XNA " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Do the artifacts exist when you view you assets in our editor of choice? If so fix them there, if not fix the rendering options you have set to prevent the artifacts from ever occurring. All you are doing is forcing any partially transparent pixels to become fully transparent with this idea you have. In other words I've very sure your attempting to fix symptoms of you problem no the source.

Comment: Also how do you import your assets this sounds like your assets are not premultiplied and your using a Blendstate in your Spritebatch that assumes the Texture2D is premultiplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Define a value that holds the current alpha state between 1 and 0. Decrement that value each frame untill it hits 0. In the draw method, you determine the alpha value of the tint color.

```
byte alpha = 255 - (currentAlphaState * 255);
spriteBatch.Draw(...., new Color( 255, 255, 255, alpha) ...); // assuming white is your default tint color
```

Comment: is there a way to get the current alpha state from a RenderTarget2D object? Im basically continuously rendering onto a persistant RenderTarget2D class, where older images are more transparent then newer images. I basically want it able to decrement pixel alpha values to 0.

Comment: Rendertarget2D doesn't have something like a 'current' alpha state. The texture can contain alpha pixels but that's irrelevant. You can store data in the Tag member of the class but what you really should look at is a Drawable game component encapsulating RenderTarget2D which stores the alpha blending state and updates its values.

Comment: you can do this too.... spriteBatch.Draw(...., Color.White * currentAlphaState,...);